# "Error: cannot find symbols" when compiling titanium module application

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I've created a titanium module and embed it on titanium module application, but every time I compile that application it will give me an error:

```
[INFO] Compiling Javascript Resources ...
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] Error(s) compiling generated Java code
[ERROR] C:\DeveloperFolder\TitaniumStudioWorkspace\TestingModuleApp\build\android\gen\testing\module\app\TestingmoduleappApplication.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TestingmoduleBootstrap
location: package testing.module
        runtime.addExternalModule("testing.module", testing.module.TestingmoduleBootstrap.class);
                                                                  ^
1 error
```

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Did you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: @Anand: i can't clean my project.. it give me 'Cleaning selected projects' has encountered a problem. Errors occurred during the build? any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Your compiler doesn't seem too sure about whether it's compiling Javascript or Java. First line mentions Javascript while the lines below that (the actual errors) seem to be about Java (two completely different languages).

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `TestingmoduleBootstrap.class` and then recompile again:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/402221/java/java/Compiler-Error-find-symbol

And make sure you don't have a typo in your class name:

http://java.about.com/od/cerrmsg/g/Definition-Cannot-Find-Symbol.htm